# Should I use Express for my simple chat application?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm creating a simple chat client which will connect to a Node.js server with Socket.io websockets.

My client js code (simplified) looks like this:

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.emit('send message', 'Hi to all');
```

My server js code (simplified) looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(7000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('send message', function(msg){
        // Code for saving the message in mysql database is ommited
        client.broadcast.emit('new message', msg);
    });
 });
```

Each message will be saved to a mysql database before it is broadcasted to other clients.

As you can see, my server js code uses Express. Is Express really needed for my needs?

I read that Express is a framework used for static file server, route management, cookie parser, form-encoded and JSON-encoded body parser, logging, view rendering and other goodies. I don't need these functions (or maybe I do but i don't know yet).

Many node.js + sockets.io examples on the internet use Express so I'm not sure if I really need it or not. Should I use the Express framework or not? If yes, why? If no, why?

Thanks

Comment: opinon based question,you'd be better off on reddit.

Comment: @mpm I bet to differ, it's a proper question if Express (that *is* almost always mentioned in `socket.io` examples) is necessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in this situation you don't need Express, because you're not using it :) `socket.io` can run without Express as well:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(7000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on('send message', function(msg){
    // Code for saving the message in mysql database is ommited
    client.broadcast.emit('new message', msg);
  });
});
```